# Java Stream Map T -> ?T:List<T>

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm new to java and love the Stream API.
I got this loop:

```
List<FileTree> expanded = new ArrayList<>();
for(FileTree item : tree){
    if(item.getType().equals("tree")){
        expanded.addAll(getTreeOfSubStudPackage(item.getName()));
    }
    else{
        expanded.add(item);
    }
}
```

And I wonder if this could be converted to a neat stream. My first guess was the following:

```
tree.stream().map(fileTree -> {
    if(fileTree.getType().equals("tree")){
        return getTreeOfSubStudPackage(fileTree.getName());
    }
    else{
        return fileTree;
    }
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It compiles fine. But is this recommended, have I even implemented a No-Go or is there a even nicer way?
And last but not least: Is there a overhead in `.stream()` that would make this improvement worthless?

### Appendix

```
List<FileTree> getTreeOfSubStudPackage(...){
    //...
}

class FileTree {
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private String mode;
    private String id;
    //... Public Getter And Setter ...
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this code works? Your lambda expression returns different types in the if and else clauses.

Comment: It seems you're looking for `.flatMap`, but your question is a bit unclear so hard to tell.

Comment: FYI your stream attempt produces a `List<Object>` containing a mixture of `FileTree` and `List<FileTree>`. The answer posted does what you intended to do.

Answer (score 2):

you need to do `map` and then `flatMap`.

`Arrays.asList(item)` is to add the element to `List` to be flat in the next `flatMap`

```
    tree.stream()
        .map(item -> item.getType().equals("tree") ? getTreeOfSubStudPackage(item.getName()) : Arrays.asList(item))
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Trick I learned from IntelliJ: `Collections.singletonList()`.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: be prepared to learn `List.of(…)` in Java 9. But here, both, `Arrays.asList` and `singletonList`, are as obsolete as the entire intermediate `List` step. Just replace the `map(…).flatMap(…)` with a single `.flatMap(item -> item.getType().equals("tree")? getTreeOfSubStudPackage(item.getName()).stream(): Stream.of(item))`